# When will the sequel of The Last Airbender be released?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Attack of the Fire Nation is still due in The Last Airbender. I am waiting for its sequel for literally a decade.

What happened? Why aren't they producing the sequel of such a successful movie? When will the sequel come out?

Comment: Why do you think the movie was successful? $319.7million box office return from a $150million budget; 5% critic and 30% audience ratings on Rotten Tomatoes; 4/10 rating on IMDB.

Comment: "There's no movie in Ba Sing Se". On a more serious note, hopefully never, because the movie had many issues like incorrect casting and is loathed by ATLA animated series fans.

Comment: I _thought_ I'd written something about this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be a sequel. In addition to the film being [critically panned](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/last_airbender), it also didn't do well enough financially to justify a sequel, let alone be the opening film of a series. Any hopes of a sequel were dashed when Nickelodeon announced in 2018 that it was going to 'reinvision' the series as a live-action show.

> We’re thrilled for the opportunity to helm this live-action adaptation
> of Avatar: The Last Airbender. We can’t wait to realize Aang’s world
> as cinematically as we always imagined it to be, and with a culturally
> appropriate, non-whitewashed cast. It’s a once-in-a-lifetime chance to
> build upon everyone’s great work on the original animated series and
> go even deeper into the characters, story, action, and world-building.
>
> <sub><sup>[Avatar: The Last Airbender creators return for live-action Netflix remake](https://www.polygon.com/2018/9/18/17874344/avatar-the-last-airbender-live-action-series-netflix)</sup></sub>

For the record, while *The Last Airbender* didn't flop, neither did it do well. Its making budget was [$150M](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl1516209665/). Add on on a marketing-spend of probably $50M (and take into account that the studio usually gets about [50-60% of box-office receipts](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/093015/how-exactly-do-movies-make-money.asp#:%7E:text=A%20studio%20might%20make%20about,the%20contract%20for%20each%20film.)) which means that its international box-office of $319M wouldn't have covered their costs.